# Difference between .eq() and .get() and :nth-child()?

Tags: jquery, function, events

I have recently been looking at optimizing my coding so that is is neater and cleaner and more compact and i have encountered a little bump in the road.

I am not 100% sure when i should use a function like `.eq()` over `.get()` or `:nth-child()`.

What would the benefits be for me to use one over the other for example, what one would be best for say, reoccurring events or, multiple functions, or just a single use function etc. I can read up on the use of them in certain events and have but sources only tell me so much and even in some cases someone may use one and the other source will use another but to do the exact same thing.

This is the 'gray' area that i need some clarification in please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `.eq(n)` retrieves the n-1<sup>th</sup> *jQuery object*.
- `.get(n)` retrieves the n-1<sup>th</sup> *DOM element*. It'd be like doing `.eq(n)[0]`.
- `:nth-child()` is for more complex selectors like `:nth-child(2n+1)`.

  You *could* use it in place of `:eq()` in selector strings, but I tend to stay away from it and use `.eq()` to make the selector more readable:

  ```
  $('ul.parent > li.child:nth-child(2)')
  $('ul.parent > li.child:eq(2)')
  $('ul.parent > li.child').eq(2)
  ```

Comment: Oh, you were faster than I :(

Comment: So i should basically use the .eq() method because it is more versatile and can be used in strings etc. Can it be used though to be called upon later on say be another function?

Comment: @Epik: They're different tools. You're asking whether to use a hammer or a screwdriver. If you need the DOM object, use `.get()`. If you need the jQuery object, use `.eq()`.

Comment: Ok well that does make it a lot clearer now thanks for that. I am accepting your answer cause it is correct and clearly explains the differences.

Comment: The first example should be $('ul.parent > li.child:nth-child(3)') because the nth-child selector is 1-indexed.