# How to handle multiple instances of a single class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, location, href

I'm not exactly sure how to handle multiple instances like this. I know in normal JS I can simply use [0] and such.

My code is this:

```
location.href = $('a.test').attr('href');
```

I need to handle both the first instance of test and the second. Is there a simple

```
location.href = $('a.test')[0].attr('href');
```

I'm missing or such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('a.test')[0]` return a dom element reference which does not have the method `attr()`, so your script will fail

use .eq(index)

```
location.href = $('a.test').eq(0).attr('href');
```

or

```
location.href = $('a.test:eq(0)').attr('href');
```

Comment: + 1 could use `first` as well see below `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call attr on javascript DOM object instead of using jQuery object as indexer returns the DOM object Use [**eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get jQuery object

```
location.href = $('a.test').eq(0).attr('href');
```

You can use DOM object with href instead of attr

```
location.href = $('a.test')[0].href;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tats_innit, same here. I left that for you :)

Comment: lol cheers, i also added `n-th child`, good to see you bruvo after long time! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

```
location.href = $('a.test').eq(0).attr('href');
```

or you can try

```
location.href = $('a.test:eq(0)').attr('href');
```

reference [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) and [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 1):

This demo might help: **working demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/CmQGu/

you can also use `nth-child` api demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/wYdyJ/

There are many ways you can approach this, like I showed you in demos. also if you keen read this : [Difference between .eq() and .get() and :nth-child()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103994/difference-between-eq-and-get-and-nth-child)

API:

- `first` : http://api.jquery.com/first/ (All the peeps up have missed this)
- `eq` : http://api.jquery.com/eq/
- `nth-child` : http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

**Code**:

```
alert(location.href = $('a.test').eq(0).attr('href'));

alert(location.href = $('a.test').first().attr('href'));

alert(location.href = $('a.test:nth-child(2)').attr('href'));
```

Hope it helps `:)`